# React - execute javascript after bootstrap modal is completely rendered and visible

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I'm working on a React front-end that uses Reactstrap, in which I'm creating my own reusable modal component. Whenever there is too much content for the modal, it becomes scrollable and to make that clear to the user, I created an indicator at the bottom of the modal. ([example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aofMP.jpg))

The indicator sticks at the bottom of the modal while scrolling and I make it disappear when the user reaches the end (check onscroll event and moreContent state in code below).

So far so good, but my problem is that I can't find a way to check if I initially have to show the indicator when rendering the modal. Right now the moreContent state is initially set to true, but that should depend on whether the modal is scrollable or not.

I tried:

- to find an event like onScroll that fires when Modal is rendered so that I can check if event.target.scrollHeight == event.target.clientHeight
- useEffect hook with a reference to the modal. This fires too soon because scrollHeight and clientHeight are still 0.

The code for my modal component:

```
    import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
    import {Button, Modal, ModalBody, ModalHeader} from "reactstrap";
    
    const MyModal = (props) => {
        const [moreContent, setMoreContent] = useState(true);
        const ref = React.useRef();
    
        useEffect(() => {
            console.log("scrollHeight", ref.current._element.scrollHeight);
            console.log("scrollTop", ref.current._element.scrollTop);
            console.log("clientHeight", ref.current._element.clientHeight);
        });
    
        const onScroll = (event) => {
            if (moreContent) {
                setMoreContent(event.target.scrollHeight - event.target.scrollTop !== event.target.clientHeight);
            }
        }
    
        return (
            <Modal isOpen={props.isOpen} toggle={props.closeHandler} centered={true} scrollable={true} className="my-modal" onScroll={onScroll} ref={ref}>
                <ModalHeader tag="div" toggle={props.closeHandler}>
                    ...
                </ModalHeader>
                <ModalBody>
                    {props.children}
                    {moreContent &&
                        <div className="modal-scroll-down">
                            <i className="fa fa-arrow-down mr-4"></i> MEER <i className="fa fa-arrow-down ml-4"></i>
                        </div>
                    }
                </ModalBody>
            </Modal>
        )
    };
    
    MyModal.defaultProps = {
        showCloseButton : true
    }
    
    export default MyModal;
```

Any tip, advice, workaround is welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you are attaching `ref` to a `Modal` which is not a DOM element and therefore will not have these properties `scrollHeight`, `scrollTop`, and `clientHeight`. Furthermore even if it was a DOM element, it is not the element with the scrollbar - it is actually `ModalBody`. But, to make matters worst, it looks like Reactstrap does not really expose a prop for you attach a [forwarded ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) to the `ModalBody`.

To solve this you can replace `ModalBody` with a `div` - this is where we can attach a `ref` to.

```
<Modal
  isOpen={props.isOpen}
  toggle={props.closeHandler}
  centered={true}
  scrollable={true}
  className="my-modal"
  onScroll={onScroll}
  onOpened={onOpened}
>
  <ModalHeader tag="div" toggle={props.closeHandler}>
    modal header
  </ModalHeader>

  <div ref={ref} style={{ overflowY: "auto", padding: "16px" }}>
    {props.children}
    {moreContent && (
      <div className="modal-scroll-down">
        <i className="fa fa-arrow-down mr-4"></i> MEER{" "}
        <i className="fa fa-arrow-down ml-4"></i>
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
</Modal>
```

Pay attention to the `onOpened` prop I attached to `<Modal>`, this answers what you sought:

> execute javascript after bootstrap modal is completely rendered and
> visible

```
const onOpened = () => {
  setMoreContent(
    ref.current.scrollHeight - ref.current.scrollTop !==
      ref.current.clientHeight
  );
};
```

[image: Edit Reactstrap Modal "Scroll Me Down"]

Comment: I found the solution yesterday aswell. I tried the onOpened prop before, but the problem was I was looking to "ref.current._element" and I needed to go down the DOM structure to the modal body div, which indeed has the scrollbar. I still have the ref on the Modal component, but I'm sure your solution works fine too. 

I'll accept your answer, it would have put me on the right track

Comment: ah you traversed to it? did you use querySelector?